# Read 9 million xml files and transfer data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, multithreading, xmltextwriter

I am using Visual Studio 2022. I have 9 million XML files and need to transfer the data into SQL Server.

I am reading in the XML through `XmlDocument`, `Xmlnode` list. It's working fine, but taking so much time to complete - around 4 hours to complete the task. With `SqlBulkCopy`, it's taking 5 minutes only.

I am reading xml file one by one. How could I read multiple XML files on each thread? I think using thread concept, I read all XML files easily.

My code:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
_xmlfiles = Directory.GetFiles(source, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();                
_xmlfiles.Remove(Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(source), "abc.xml"));
_xmlfiles.Remove(Path.Combine(Path.GetFullPath(source), "xyz.xml"));
            
WriteLog(_logPath, string.Format("{0} |xml files are found in given path.{1}", DateTime.Now,_xmlfiles.Count ));
DataTable _table = /* code for get table structure */;

foreach (string _xmlfile in _xmlfiles)
{
    _casFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_xmlfile);
    LoadXml(_xmlfile, _table);                    
}
           
WriteLog(_logPath, string.Format("{0} |Reading the files is completed,Found the Total Phrases {1}.",DateTime.Now, _table.Rows.Count ));

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(_table);

_sqlWriter = new SQLWriter();

WriteLog(_logPath, string.Format("{0} |Writing Phrases into data base is started......",DateTime.Now ));

_sqlWriter.AutoSqlBulkCopy(ds);
```

Load XML method:

```
XmlDocument _casFile = new XmlDocument();
_casFile.Load(xmlfile);

XmlNodeList _instanceList = _casFile.SelectNodes("Specification/Substance/Property/Instance");

foreach (XmlNode _instance in _instanceList)
{
    string _day = _instance.Attributes["DD"].Value;
    string _month = _instance.Attributes["MM"].Value;
    string _year = _instance.Attributes["YYYY"].Value;
    string _active =_instance.Attributes["Active"].Value;
    _uniqueID = _instance.Attributes["UniqueID"].Value;                    
    _baseCode = _instance.Attributes["LitSource"].Value;                    

    XmlNodeList _phraseList = _instance.SelectNodes("Fields/Phrases");

    foreach (XmlNode _phrase in _phraseList)
    {
        string _Characteristic = _phrase.Attributes["ID"].Value;
        XmlNodeList _childList = _phrase.ChildNodes;

        foreach(XmlNode _child in _childList)
        {
            DataRow row = table.NewRow();
            row["Substance"] = _substance;
            row["UniqueID"] = _uniqueID;
            row["Characteristic"] = _Characteristic;
            row["PhraseID"] = _child.Attributes["Key"].Value;

            if (_child.Attributes["Code"] != null)
            {
                row["Code"] = _child.Attributes["Code"].Value;
            }
            else
            {
                row["Code"] = string.Empty;
            }

            row["BaseCode"] = _baseCode;                            
            row["Description"] = _child.InnerText;
            row["Active"] = _active;
            row["DD"] = _day;
            row["MM"] = _month;
            row["YYYY"] = _year;

            table.Rows.Add(row);
        }                        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use **internationally understood** measurements - hundreds, thousands, millions etc.

Comment: Reading and parsing 9 million of files can take some time even with threads

Comment: It is better to use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) for such tasks. It has *XML Source Adapter* to ingest XML files.

Comment: The is 1.6msec a file. How large is each file?  That is extremely fast.  I don't think any method would be faster.

Comment: Are you simply loading the XML files into the server, or are you transforming them first?  How different is the XML you upload to the server from the original XML? Also, have you profiled to see where you are taking time?

Comment: It's one thing to open a file with 9M records, another to open 9M files with 1 record. In the second case you pay the file overhead 9M times

Comment: Just a side note: You can probably use null-propagating and null coalescing operators to simplify the "code" assignment as `row["Code"] = _child.Attributes["Code"]?.Value ?? string.Empty;`, eliminating the if-else. (This is just a style thing with has negligible performance improvement - one less attribute lookup.)

Comment: @satish - try the ```Parallel.ForEach``` method

Comment: You could probably increase performance here by using something like AutoMapper to create datareaders to feed the data into SqlBulkCopy in a streaming fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform all of the XML parsing and table insert operations on the SQL Server side by defining a stored procedure that encapsulates all of that logic. The C# application could then read the XML file and just pass the entire XML string to that stored procedure.

I am not sure what the performance difference would be, but I suspect the SQL Server set operations would be some improvement. The number of objects created on the C# side and the number of calls between the application and the SQL server instance would also be reduced.

Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadCasTableFromXMl @CasXml XML
AS
    INSERT CasTable(Substance, UniqueID, Characteristic, PhraseID, Code, 
                    BaseCode, Description, Active, DD, MM, YYYY)
    SELECT
        'Unknown _substance' AS Substance,
        I.Instance.value('(@UniqueID)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS UniqueID,
        P.Phrase.value('(@ID)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Characteristic,
        C.Child.value('(@Key)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS PhraseID,
        ISNULL(C.Child.value('(@Code)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), '') AS Code,
        I.Instance.value('(@LitSource)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS BaseCode,
        C.Child.value('(text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Description,
        I.Instance.value('(@Active)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Active,
        I.Instance.value('(@DD)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS DD,
        I.Instance.value('(@MM)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS MM,
        I.Instance.value('(@YYYY)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS YYYY
    FROM @CasXml.nodes('/Specification/Substance/Property/Instance') I(Instance)
    CROSS APPLY I.Instance.nodes('./Fields/Phrases') P(Phrase)
    CROSS APPLY P.Phrase.nodes('./*') C(Child)
```

Or perhaps:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoadCasTableFromXMl @CasXmlText NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    DECLARE @CasXml XML = @CasXmlText
    ...
```

Lacking details, I've just assumed `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for all columns. Hopefully, your table has properly typed columns, and the above code should be modified to use the correct types. (I also hope that your end table does not store dates as separate `YYYY`, `MM`, and `DD` columns. This is a bad practice and you should use a single column properly typed as `DATE`.)

Sample results:

| Substance | UniqueID | Characteristic | PhraseID | Code | BaseCode | Description | Active | DD | MM | YYYY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Unknown _substance | 111 | 1 | Key1 | Code1 | AAA | Description1 | True | 31 | 12 | 2023 |
| Unknown _substance | 111 | 1 | Key2 |  | AAA | Description2 | True | 31 | 12 | 2023 |
| Unknown _substance | 222 | 1 | Key3 | Code3 | BBB | Description3 | False | 01 | 01 | 2024 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sM9G5zPW) for a demo.

Comment: I doubt it actually is faster. The XML being transferred is almost certainly larger than the amount of data that `SqlBulkCopy` would transfer, and bulk-copy is very efficient anyway.

Comment: @Charlieface I was considering the object lifetime overhead involved with the DataTable/DataRow construction and cleanup within the application and the handshaking (number of calls / number of parameters for the resulting insert statements) between the application and SQL server - especially if each source file is mapped to multiple rows. In any case, it was offered up as a possible improvement. Whether that is 1% or 50% - only testing would show.  But agree, if SQL Server has a bulkcopy that can directly map XML files to tables, that's the way to go.

Comment: tried the code, but not working. its not showing any error also. i waited for 4 hours, not and kept the break point in main method, its not working. var _options = new ParallelOptions()
                { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2
                };
                Parallel.ForEach(_xmlfiles,_options, _xmlfile =>
                 {
                     LoadXml(_xmlfile, _table);
                 });   did i need to use the Thread.sleep?

Comment: @satish When you are performance tuning, it is best not to try to run all 9 million files at once, Try just a few at first. then 100, then 1000, and then 10000. From those results, calculate what the estimated total run time would be. For example: If 10000 files takes 1 minute, 9 million files might take 15 hours. If 10000 files takes 1 hour, 9 million files might take over a month, and you probably need to try other ways to improve performance. When you do the final run, I suggest running the imports in batches that are sized so that each completes within a few minutes to an hour.

Answer (score -1):

You should use Linq and the .AsParallel() method if you are sure that the way you insert stuff into the database has no order dependency.

I am not sure exactly how you implement this, but Microsoft has a nice example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-iterate-file-directories-with-the-parallel-class

You should probably not load the xml file when you test your solution, but do something simple instead. Perhaps change your method to receive an Action to execute when it resolves an xml file path.

Comment: i tried the code, but not working.  its not showing any error also. i waited for 4 hours, not and kept the break point in main method, its not working.                                                           Parallel.ForEach(_xmlfiles, _xmlfile =>
                 {
                     LoadXml(_xmlfile, _table);
                 });